# React Native can't find variable:style?

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    placeName: ""
  }

  PlaceNameChangerHandler = val => {
    this.setState({
      placeName: val
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputcontainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="A awsome place"
            value={this.state.placeName}
            onChangeText={this.PlaceNameChangerHandler}
            style={style.placeinput}
          />
          <Button title="Addd" style={style.placebutton} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 50,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
  },
  inputcontainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  placeinput: {
    width: "70%"
  },
  placebutton: {
    width: "30%"
  }

});
```

Comment: style= {styles.placebutton}   change your Style.placebutton to Styles and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet is named `styles`

Answer (score 0):

Change your render method to this and it should work, just replace style with styles :

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputcontainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="A awsome place"
            value={this.state.placeName}
            onChangeText={this.PlaceNameChangerHandler}
            style={styles.placeinput}
          />
          <Button title="Addd" style={styles.placebutton} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```